# calling setState from the parent widget in flutter does not update the state

Tags: flutter, flutter-android, flutter-state, flutter-build, flutter-onpressed

### Parent Widget

```
class _FamilyListPageState extends State<FamilyListPage> {
  String initialValue = 'Search Families';

  void eraseInitialValue() {     <-------------- This function is passed down to the child widget
    setState(() {
      initialValue = '';
      print('Inside the set state');    <-------- This line gets executed.
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Search Families'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: StaticEntry.backColor,
        body: Center(
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.8,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SearchInput(   <----------------------------------------- Child Widget
                  initialValue: initialValue,
                  onTapHandler: eraseInitialValue,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Child Widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialValue;
  final Function onTapHandler;      <----------- Function from the parent widget is stored in here

  SearchInput({this.initialValue, this.onTapHandler});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 40,
          ),
          title: Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: initialValue,
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  letterSpacing: 1),
              onTap: onTapHandler,         <--------------- This is where I have made a pointer at the function received from the parent widget to be executed when tapped.
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Background

I have a child widget which holds a **TextFormField**. The **initialValue** of that **TextFormField** is **'Search Families'**. I am trying to erase that initial value when the user taps on that **TextFormField** so the user can type what he/she wants in that **TextFormField** without erasing it manually by themselves.

### What I have done

To achieve this I have made my parent widget a **stateful widget**. State of my parent widget has an instance variable called **initialValue** that holds the value **'Search Families'** which is used to configure the **initialValue** property of the **TextFormField** inside the child widget.

Then I have defined a method inside the parent widget called **eraseInitialValue** which resets the value of the **initialValue** instance variable to an empty string by calling the **setState**.

Finally inside the child widget, I am giving a pointer at this function for the **onTap** property of the **TextFormField** to execute the declared function which in turn should update the state of the application.

### Problem

However, the text **'Search Families'** never changes.

(I added a print statement inside the **setState** to see if the function holding the **setState** gets executed. It indeed does. But the state is not updated.)

Can someone help me understand this code is not working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

onTapHandler() instead onTapHandler in `SearchInput` class

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `GestureDetector`? Please update your code and give feedback.

**Parent Widget**

```
class _FamilyListPageState extends State<FamilyListPage> {
  String initialValue = 'Search Families';

  void eraseInitialValue() {     <-------------- This function is passed down to the child widget
    setState(() {
      initialValue = '';
      print('Inside the set state');    <-------- This line gets executed.
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Search Families'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        backgroundColor: StaticEntry.backColor,
        body: Center(
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: 0.8,
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () { eraseInitialValue(); },
                  child: SearchInput( <----------------------------------------- Child Widget
                    initialValue: initialValue,
                    //onTapHandler: eraseInitialValue,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Child Widget**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SearchInput extends StatelessWidget {
  final String initialValue;
  final Function onTapHandler;      <----------- Function from the parent widget is stored in here

  SearchInput({this.initialValue, this.onTapHandler});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            size: 40,
          ),
          title: Container(
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () { onTapHandler(); },
              child: TextFormField(
                initialValue: initialValue,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                  letterSpacing: 1),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this. But still the result is the same. I also tried wrapping the parent widget with a `GestureDetector` and calling the `eraseInitialValue` function from there. But still no luck.....

Comment: Create a simple class that will do a `print("It worked so far");` Call this function in the `onTap` method and see if it was at least print

Comment: I tried what you said. The print `"It works so far works!"`. Also even in the class I had (not the test class we created now), when I add a print statement inside that function, upon tapping on the child widget, that print function is executed. It is only that the state is not updated!

Comment: Anyone got answer for this? I'm having similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70235200/flutter-callback-function-not-called-while-trying-to-call-setstate-from-child